# When creating a new branch, which branch does it copy?

Tags: git, github

If I'm in the `master` branch, and I create a new branch, will the new branch have the contents of master? Is this the case every time? For example, what if I then go to my `feature` branch and create a new one while in there, will it contain the contents of the feature branch but be a new one?

Comment: Creating a Git branch, by itself, really just creates a pointer to a certain commit.  Assuming you create a `feature` branch from `master`, it would just point to the HEAD commit of the current `master` branch.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part here is that the basic question is not well formed.  The problem here is actually the word *branch*, which has more than one meaning.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

If and when you mean *branch name*, well, each branch's name has one value: a commit hash ID.  So if you're on `master`, and `master` has, say, hash ID `a123456...`, and you run:

```
git branch newname
```

(successfully), you've just created a new branch name `newname` that *also* has hash ID `a123456...`.  In that sense, you could claim to have copied branch `master`.

But the word *branch* also means *a collection of commits ending at the designated tip commit*.  You have not copied any *commits*, so by the same logic, you have not copied anything at all.

I think that for many people, a picture helps.  Imagine a Git branch this way: it's a series of commits.  Each commit has some unique hash ID: a big ugly string of letters and digits—technically, a number expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)—that Git uses to find that particular commit, in the big database that Git has that holds all the internal Git objects, including the commit objects.  Rather than writing down those hash IDs, though, we'll just use single uppercase letters to stand in for each one, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *last* commit in this sequence.  (Obviously then, older commits are on the left, and newer commits are on the right.)  Commit `H` has two parts: data (a snapshot) and metadata (information about the commit), and the metadata include the hash ID of the *previous* commit in the chain: the hash ID `G`.  So commit `H` *points to* commit `G`.

Commit `G` itself also has two parts, snapshot and metadata, and its metadata contain the raw hash ID of earlier commit `F`.  `G`, then, points to `F`.

This means the commits themselves, in a Git repository, form a backwards-looking chain.  All we need to do is find the *last* commit in the chain, and point Git to that particular commit.  From there, Git can zip along, backwards, through the history—the commits in the chain—to find earlier versions.  Each commit has a full snapshot of every file, so comparing the earlier files to the later files—a `git diff`—tells us what *changed*.

We do, however, need a way to find these *last* or *tip* commits.  The tip commit of any particular chain is where we start: at the end.  To *find* these tip commits, Git allows us to use names.  The names can be any kind of name, not just a *branch* name, but branch names have one special property: using those names with `git checkout` or `git switch`, we get "on the branch".

So, if we have a chain like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

then the branch name `master` identifies commit `H`.  To make a *new* branch, we simply pick one of these commits and tell Git: *make a new branch name and point it at that commit*.  If we don't pick one, Git picks the *current* commit; if we do pick one we can get, e.g.:

```
...--F--G   <-- previous
         \
          H   <-- master
```

We'd get this with `git branch previous hash-id`, where *`hash-id`* is the hash ID of commit `G`.  We could find that particular hash ID using, e.g., `git log`.<sup>1</sup>  Of course, now that we have *two* branch names, we need a way to indicate which name we're actually using:

```
...--F--G   <-- previous
         \
          H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Here, the special name `HEAD` is attached to the branch name `master`, indicating that we're still on `master` and hence still using commit `H`.  If we run `git checkout previous` or `git switch previous`, we'll get:

```
...--F--G   <-- previous (HEAD)
         \
          H   <-- master
```

which means we will be using the name `previous` and commit `G`.

Whenever we make a *new* commit, Git:

1. writes out a snapshot of all files;
2. gathers and writes out the appropriate metadata, to produce the new commit, with its new unique hash ID; and
3. writes the *new* commit's hash ID into the *current branch name*.

The appropriate metadata, in step 2, includes the *current commit* as the parent of the new commit.  So in the state in the last drawing, if we make a new commit on `previous`, we get:

```
          I   <-- previous (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G
         \
          H   <-- master
```

and now our branches have diverged.  If we go back to `master`:

```
          I   <-- previous
         /
...--F--G
         \
          H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and then make a new name `feature` pointing to commit `H`, get on `feature`, and make one new commit on `feature`, we get:

```
          I   <-- previous
         /
...--F--G
         \
          H   <-- master
           \
            J   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

You can create and delete branch names at any time you like.  There are just two rules:

1. A branch name *must* point to some existing commit (always).
2. You cannot delete the branch name you have `HEAD` attached to.

There's a third thing you should watch out for, but it's not a hard and fast rule:

3. It's a bad idea to delete the only name that lets you find a commit.

In our example above, if you now delete the *name* `previous`, you get:

```
          I   ???
         /
...--F--G
         \
          H   <-- master
           \
            J   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Hash IDs *look* random (though they actually aren't random at all).  How will you ever find commit `I` again?  It would be easy if you could see its hash ID, but if you can't ... well, there are some [clues in the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), but we'll leave this all for later.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are *many* ways to name a commit.  [The gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) covers this.  Note that it is full of jargon, and condenses a lot of information into a very small space, so you'll likely have to re-read it many times.